# File never gets created

Tags: python, file-handling

Im trying to write and execute a .vbs file with python. When I run the program, the IDE shows an error that the file I tried to make isn't there, so therefore it couldn't be executed. I followed exactly the documentation in python.org and other similar questions in stack overflow but they didn't give a good answer to my problem. Here is the code I tried to run:

```
import os
a = open('draw.vbs','w+')
a.write('do\nSet oWMP = CreateObject(\"WMPlayer.OCX.7\")\nSet colCDROMs             oWMP.cdromCollection\nif colCDROMs.count >= 1\ncolCDROMs.Item(i).eject\nNext  cdrom\nEnd If\nloop')
b = os.system('draw.vbs')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `with` statement.

```
with open('draw.vbs', 'w+') as a:
    a.write('do\nSet oWMP = CreateObject(\"WMPlayer.OCX.7\")\nSet colCDROMs
b = os.system('draw.vbs')
```

Comment: Tried that too but it didn't work. The problem is the file didn't get created in the first place.

Comment: @Nebraska are you sure you have write permissions for that folder?

Comment: I don't know. I t never gets created in the first place

Comment: Im lost. Are there any webpages that can help me.